# How do you enable test coverage in Rider

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rider, test-coverage

I was looking for it for a while, but couldn't find a way to enable the test coverage features in the Rider Unit Test tool window. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Unit_Tests_Coverage_window.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The keyword is dotCover, you need to enable it manually in File => Settings => Plugins => search for "dotCover" and enable it.

[image]

Comment: Looking at my current rider (2022.2.1 build #RD-222.3739.37 from 8th Autust 2022), this has moved now to File => Settings => "Build, Execution, Deployment" => dotCover.

Comment: @anmatr This is where the dotCover settings reside _after_ having enabled the plugin.

Comment: I went to plugins and couldn't find it, neither in marketplace nor in installed. I do have a "coverage" option in `Build, Execution, Deployment` though, but no options there

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, for me dotcover plugin was also missing in marketplace in Rider, because it was already installed, but was not enabled (why?). You might be able to find it in the list of installed plugins, check the enablement checkbox and then save to enable.

Answer (score 0):

once you enable the plugin please do restart your ide... still if you do not see the code coverage icon in similar manner then try to check again if plugin have been added or not else add and try to restart IDE-rider.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's not there. If it was, I would see it.